# VBA Matching across different sheets

Tags: excel, vba

New to VBA. I have three sheets: Sheet 1 and Sheet 2 track information for two different parts. Both sheets have a column named: "Set Number" where values range from 1-8. I'm trying to then extract ID Numbers (Cell(a9)downwards) of the parts with matching Set Numbers to Sheet 3.

On Sheet 3 Column 1 would pull from Sheet 1 and Column 2 would pull from Sheet 2 for Set 1; Columns 3 and for would do the same for Set 2, etc.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Why use `VBA` and not just `INDEX`/`MATCH`?

Comment: I tried using INDEX/MATCH before switching to VBA, but could not get more than a single cell to be matched to Sheet 3. I'm not very familiar with this function either, to be honest, most of what I tried revolved around VLOOKUPs.